# Linux apps don't scale properly in Chrome OS with high resolution displays

Tags: google-chrome-os, high-dpi, debian-stretch

Just got an Acer Spin 13, which has a 2K display. When I run Linux apps, the entire application is tiny: fonts, icons, etc. I understand that this is a result of the resolution scaling tricks Chrome OS does, and I discovered that there is an option to "Use Low Density", if you right-click the Linux app icon in the dock. While this fixes the main issue (everything is the right size), it's blurry as heck.

I know that Linux command-line, but haven't had much experience dealing with the GUI side of things. Does anyone know if there's something I can can tweak, some app I can utilize, etc. to help with the HDPI scaling issues? Or, maybe something specific to Chrome OS I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you haven't found your answer, there still doesn't seem to be a "point-and-click" option available; we've got two CLI options, though:

1. Set the scaling factor within the app settings/config, or at launch: e.g., 
   `atom --force-device-scale-factor=2`
2. Set the HiDPI Scaling via Sommelier config [globally](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/comments/9g1ovl/scale_and_dpi_in_sommelierrc/) or [per a given app](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/howto/adjust-display-scaling#wiki_adjusting_display_scaling_per_application).

Atom's the only GUI app I'm running and the runtime flag *does*, in fact, provide me with text that is both not blurry *and* large enough to read without a magnifying glass, so I didn't devote much time to playing with Sommelier; YMMV.